# A working example of the Kafka connectr mongoDB source?

Tags: mongodb, apache-kafka-connect

I can't make it work.

Here my json configuration:

```
{
  "name": "lastlook-mongodb-source-connector",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "com.mongodb.kafka.connect.MongoSourceConnector",
    "tasks.max": "4",
    "connection.uri": "mongodb://user:pass@machine1:27017,machine2:27017/?authSource=admin",
    "database": "DB",
    "collection": "Collection",
    "topic": "Topic",
    "startup_mode": "copy_existing",
    "pipeline":"[]",
    "change.stream.full.document":"updateLookup",
    "producer.override.sasl.mechanism": "SCRAM-SHA-256",
    "producer.override.security.protocol": "SASL_PLAINTEXT",
    "producer.override.sasl.jaas.config": "org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required username=\"user\" password=\"pass\";"
  }
}
```

But for some reason I have the error:

> {"error_code":400,"message":"Connector configuration is invalid and contains the following 1 error(s):\nInvalid user permissions. Missing the following action permissions: changeStream\nYou can also find the above list of errors at the endpoint `/connector-plugins/{connectorType}/config/validate`"}

Which is not clear at all.

Any info on this ?

EDIT:

As @Sara M. mentioned it was due to a lack of privilege on the mongodb "user" I used to connect to the database.

You need to add the changeStream privilege to that user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check first if the user you are using in "connection.uri" has the necessary permissions to perform the changeStream action in MongoDB.

The **changeStream** action is required for the action that you are trying to do ( "change.stream.full.document":"updateLookup").

Try to add the permission to the user or use an other user with the necessary permissions like **root**.